# String interpolation into a variable

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to insert a person's name into the body of an email as dynamic values using string interpolation in c# 6.0.

### Proof of Concept

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
        var msg = $"{p.FirstName} says 'Hello World!'";
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {msg}");
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This proof of concept outputs the string:

> Message: John says 'Hello World!'

### Implementation

So now when I'm trying to use the concept to build my MailMessage, I'm getting `{Contact.FirstName}` output in my email. Here's the code:

```
private string _Body;
public string Body
{
    get { return _Body; }
    set
    {
        _Body = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Body");
    }
}

var Contacts = Context.Contacts
  .Where(x => x.ContactGroupId == ContactGroupId && x.Deleted == false);

// By this point, Body will already have a value containing the interpolation.
// For example: Body = "Message: {Contact.Name} says \"Hello World!\"";
foreach (var Contact in Contacts)
{
    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
    
    MailMessage.Body = ${Body}
}
```

### Problem

This should render the body to read as:

> Message: John says "Hello World!"

Instead, what renders is:

> Message: {Contact.FirstName} says "Hello World!"

How can I interpolate my variables into the string if I'm not actually hard coding the string in my code?

Comment: String interpolation is a compile time feature. It cannot be used to replace tokens at runtime.

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Should be `MailMessage.Body = $"{Body}"`...

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/c-6-string-interpolation-is-not-a-templating-engine-and-it-s-not-the-new-string-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${Body}` doesn't compile.

You can't generate the interpolation at run-time, it is a syntactic sugar that gets transformed by the compiler into `String.Format`.

You can solve your problem by using `Replace` from `StringBuilder` or `String`:

```
sb.Replace("{p.FirstName}", p.FirstName);
```

Comment: String.Format is fine but won't it have the same problem? Anyway I can't have the user typing in {0} {1} etc tags in the mail body when he's writing the email... Suppose I could always leave it as `{Contact.FirstName}` and then .Replace() the hell out of it...

Comment: @Ortund Yes, that's what you need to do, though I suggest using `StringBuilder` for that.

Comment: @Ortund You can solve your problem multiple ways, String.Replace is one of the options.  `String.Replace("{p.FirstName}", p.FirstName);` StringBuilder is a better option though.

Comment: I guess either way I go, the issue of interpolation is now moot so accepting an answer becomes a strange issue

Comment: @Ortund Actually it's a valid question, I'm sure other people have had the same issue.

Comment: In that case I've accepted the answer "Don't do it, use string replacement instead" :P

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation is a compile-time feature. That’s why you can [do some neat things like](http://thebillwagner.com/Blog/Item/2015-07-05-StringInterpolationandtheConditionalOperators):

```
Console.WriteLine($"When {condition} is true, {(condition ? "it's true!" : "It's False")}");
```

You are essentially **putting C# code inside the string**!

However, if it were implemented as a dynamic feature where you could load strings and have them evaluate at runtime, then you would have a security risk much like the use of `eval` in JavaScript. It makes sense, then, that it wouldn’t be possible to do what you want to do.